# Maven dependencies are not getting updated after taking latest version of code

Tags: maven, tfs

`Maven dependencies` are not getting updated automatically after taking the latest version from `TFS`.

The Project has a red color mark and `pom.xml` file shows (x) mark.

Please let me know how to resolve this issue and update maven dependencies.

[image: maven java project]

Comment: I have no idea what "TFS" is.  Your screenshot doesn't show anything relevant that I can tell.  If you hover your mouse cursor over the pom.xml in the package explorer, it should show a balloon tip telling you what the problem is.  That information would be helpful in diagnosing your problem.

Comment: @BillHileman TFS is a SVM called Team Foundation Server. With such a non-descriptive name, it is, you guessed it, a Microsoft product.

Comment: Check that you have properly configured maven (repositories are configured correctly). When you download a project it just have pom.xml. You should have maven configured locally (either as a part of eclipse or as a standalone build)

Comment: you can delete the whole Project and Pull again from git or tfs u have to delete workspace too in your system

Answer (score 1):

First of all, let me tell you that I am not familiar with TFS in particular but I am assuming it is similar to Git or any other Version Control system. Also, I am taking the liberty of assuming that this issue is not due to an error in your POM xml.

First, you can try force updating the Project by using the option in Eclipse.
Right click on the Project > Maven > Update Project.

[image: Eclipse - Maven - Update Project]

If that doesn't fix the error,
You may go and manually delete the local maven repository and then follow the above process. Remember to backup maven repo or any files before deleting so that you can revert back to the previous state if that doesn't work.